# static pointer to N arrays, or pointer to N static arrays?

Tags: c++, c

I have the following codes:

```
const int N=3;
static double * p[N];
```

Does p stands for a static pointer pointing to a N-dimensional double array, or a N-dimensional array with each elements standing for a static pointer?

Also I found the following change failed compilation, and not sure why...

```
int N=3;
static double * p[N];
```

Comment: Just a tip based on this and your previous question: You need to stop thinking of `static` as being part of the type. It's not. You work out the type of the thing ("array of N pointer to double" in this case) and then you can say it's static. Whatever that object is made up of will have static storage duration. If your type contains pointers, whatever they point to is not part of the object. They are different objects entirely and are not necessarily static. The declaration in your question doesn't create any `double`s at all. It just creates some pointers. Those pointers are static.

Comment: @sftrabbit It's clearer to me now that "static" is not part of the type. E.g. "int * a, b;" declares "a" as a pointer, whereas "b" as an "int"; however, "int static a, b;" declare both "a" and "b" has a "static" duration. Am I right?

Comment: Well `a` is a "pointer to int" and `b` is just an "int". But yes, both `a` and `b` will be static in your second example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does p stands for a static pointer pointing to a N-dimensional double array, or a N-dimensional array with each elements standing for a static pointer?

Almost the second choice *a N-sized array with each elements standing for a static pointer*. Note the change from "N-dimensional" to "N-sized". Thanks @David.

> Also I found the following change failed compilation, and not sure why...

Arrays need constant integers for their size. After you remove the "constness" of `N` the size of `p` is uncertain at compile time.

Comment: @David My lecturers also sometimes use this ambiguous terminology. It confuses me too.

Comment: const-qualified objects are not compile-time constants, they are just objects that leads to undefined behavior if changed after their initialization. Those arrays are VLAs, both of them (compile with `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic`). In fact, arrays doesn't need constants for their size from C99 - through in C11 VLAs support is not mandatory.

Comment: @effeffe, the question is also C++ tagged. There is no VLA on C++.

Comment: @Nick: you're right, forgot to mention that I was talking about the C situation. It's not really a "both C/C++" question, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`p` is a static array of 3 pointers to `double`s.

The compiler requires the size of the array to be known at compile time, which is why you can only use a `const int` and not an `int` for the array size declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
cdecl> explain static double *p[10];
declare p as static array 10 of pointer to double
```

There's also cdecl.org for getting that kind of help online.